# Best way to load external content to site (I own all sites) (no iframes?)

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe, load

I have an ever growing medley of websites that I own (WordPress for the most part if that helps).

Each one has a VERY simple "name, a graphic, and social media links" page on it at **foo.domain.com/partner**.

I would like for **a.domain.com** to be able to load content from 3 other sites into their sidebar with OUT iframes.

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe even with `.load()`? You can't load external content like that I believe, so I'm not sure the best way to approach this. Iframes aren't really cutting it.

Again, I have rights to ALL of the sites, and I have access to add PHP/Jquery scripts anywhere on them all.

Comment: Have you tried [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/)?

Comment: If they're all WordPress sites, shouldn't it be possible to generate an RSS feed of the content from each site and reassemble the collected content from that?

Comment: @Blazemonger - yes, but i didn't want to rely on the RSS feeds to regenerate content. It didn't quite suit my needs for this application, though I did consider/try it

Comment: I still think it would be easier, since by using RSS you're getting just the content to format as you need, while using PHP to scrape the website gives you all the styling and layout that you might not want. But, you know your needs best.

Comment: They are already styled as I need them. It's very very basic styling, though necessary - including social media sprites etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this:

1. PHP can `file_get_contents()` or `cURL` content from other sites and then work with the content server side (load content before it's sent to the browser)
2. If you are generating content from databases (as you would be in WP) you can connect directly to the MySQL database of your other sites and work accordingly (make sure that you set up MySQL users that can access from the IPs of your other sites (also a server-side method)
3. Set up [cross-domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) permissions for javascript and use ajax to load in content (i.e. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`)

Comment: @AlexDemchak `file_get_contents` does no parsing... it just grabs the whole output file and loads it into a PHP string variable. You can then do what you want with it (including parsing with the PHP DOM or XML functions.

Comment: Wonderful! It works beautifully! Much better than iframes! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

How about JSONP requests? You can avoid the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) violation.

Comment: I looked into this after you mentioned it - and I will definitely look into it more! I believe the other answers suits my needs currently, but I would like to implement this at some point

Answer (score -5):

$("#loaddiv").load("directory/file.php").fadeIn("fast");

Comment: @arxanas gets it - my issue is that it's cross domain (subdomains) and  so I haven't been able to use a strict `.load()`. I have a function in each site that utilizes `.load()`, but it's to query an extension of a loop WITHIN that subdomain - my issue is loading external content, sans-iframe.